# Convert decoded frames to WAV format using ffmpeg libraries

Tags: c++, audio, encoding, ffmpeg, wav

I have a stl queue of pointers to decoded frames on the heap
(e.g. `decode_queue<AVFrame *>`)
 and I want to take those frames from the stl queue and encode them in WAV format. I tried using the examples that come with ffmpeg they break when I try to change the encoder to pcm_s32le/pcm_s16le. For example for decoding_encoding.c example, I just tried to change some parameters and all of a sudden I am getting a floating point exception.
Is there a something I can do? I am really lost.

**UPDATE**
In decoding_encoding.c i changed the line:

`codec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_MP2);`

to

`codec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_PCM_S16LE);`

this changed ended up making the `c->frame_size == 0` So the buffer is never created:

`buffer_size = av_samples_get_buffer_size(NULL, c->channels, c->frame_size,
                                             c->sample_fmt, 0);`

In that case instead of the line:

`frame->nb_samples     = c->frame_size;`

I changed it to

`frame->nb_samples     = 10000`

and

`buffer_size = av_samples_get_buffer_size(NULL, c->channels, 10000,
                                             c->sample_fmt, 0);`

just to see what happens(basically substituted `c->frame_size` for 10000). It compiles but it creates an output file but the player cannot find a stream for it or it is filled with garbage. At this point I am still stuck not sure what to do to get the output.WAV file.

Also, is a RIFF header automatically added or do I have to manually add it in as well?

Comment: Can you please give information on what exactly you changed in `decoding_encoding.c`, and where the exception is thrown?

Comment: Well, `c->frame_size`, according to the documentation, simply means that `CODEC_CAP_VARIABLE_FRAME_SIZE` is set, which it is (`codec->capabilities & 0x10000 > 0`). However, `buffer_size` is -22 when I apply your changes, i.e., `EINVAL`. Which is ok according to the source of `av_samples_get_buffer_size` (see the first if clause). Setting the frame size to, e.g. 64, I get an output. Not sure whether it actually worked or just produced garbage, though. :)

Comment: I ended up making my own from scratch. I saw the CODEC_CAP_VARIABLE_FRAME_SIZE is set for the PCM codecs.

Comment: Problem I am running into now is the header size is not 44-bytes which I am tyring to figure out, but have no idea where to start.